# Opencart. Скидка в зависимости от категории

Tags: opencart

Как допилить total.
Мне нужно чтобы скидка от суммы заказа считалась только для товаров из определенной категории.

Comment: Например, делать проверку товара на наличие его в определённой категории и, если условие соблюдено (товар есть в категории) - делаем скидку. Какой вопрос, такой и ответ. С экстрасенсорикой у меня плохо.

Comment: Используйте сторонние модули. Например, Discount Sales PRO - платный, но делает как раз что вам надо.